# angularjs ng-repeat table with nested table element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view where I displaying basic customer information (Name and email) and inside it there is customer details table.

I tried to write ng-repeat in tbody section but child table not getting the data and it's printed only once.

Also I tried to use `ng-repeat-start ng-repeat-end` but I'm getting errors that no matching `ng-repeat-end` is found

> Error: [$compile:uterdir] Unterminated attribute, found
>   'ng-repeat-start' but no matching 'ng-repeat-end' found.

my code:

```
<table class="customer">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="first">Customer Name <span class="sortable"></span></th>
      <th class="opp-detail">Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="customer in customerList">
    <tr>
      <td>{{customer.Name}}</td>
      <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.EMail}}</td>

      <table class="customer-details collapsed" >
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="opp-detail">Name</th>
          <th class="opp-detail">Address</th>
          <th class="opp-detail">City</th>
          <th class="opp-detail">Zip Code</th>
          <th class="opp-detail">Contact</th>
          <th class="opp-detail">Email</th>
          <th class="opp-detail">Phone</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.Name}}</td>
          <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.Address}}</td>
          <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.City}}</td>
          <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.PostCode}}</td>
          <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.Contact}}</td>
          <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.EMail}}</td>
          <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.PhoneNo}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas how it should be solved?

---

Test data:

```
[{ _id: 569fa2ab011d2ddc3065b802,
Name: 'Gicom',
SearchName: 'GICOM',
Address: 'some address',
Address2: '',
City: '',
Contact: '',
PhoneNo: '123456',
FaxNo: '',
PostCode: '',
Country: '',
EMail: 'mail@test.com',
MonitoringSource: 'US',
__v: 0 },
{ _id: 569fa2ab011d2ddc3065b803,
Name: 'Mitsui',
SearchName: 'MITSUI',
Address: '',
Address2: '',
City: '',
Contact: '',
PhoneNo: '',
FaxNo: '',
PostCode: '',
Country: '',
EMail: '',
MonitoringSource: 'US',
__v: 0 },
{ _id: 569fa2ab011d2ddc3065b804,
Name: 'Icon',
SearchName: 'ICON',
Address: 'customer address',
Address2: '',
City: 'some city',
Contact: '',
PhoneNo: '789456',
FaxNo: '',
PostCode: '',
Country: '',
EMail: 'mymail@test.com',
MonitoringSource: 'US',
__v: 0 }]
```

Comment: What does your `customerList` object look like?

Comment: I think you should use nested tables for that.

Comment: 1. Remove ng-repeat from tbody and put it on tr. 2. Check how many records exist in database. 3. Check if you are using "LIMIT 1" in your backend query for fetching the records. If yes, remove it.  Lastly, share the `customerList` object.

Comment: I added customerList object data to my post

Comment: @AntiHeadshot can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @intentarr Never mind, i got confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine with few adjustments. I cleaned it up a little for you. Try my solution below & let me know if you have any questions:

**Solution (Revised for Nested tables):**

```
<table class="customer table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="first">Customer Name <span class="sortable"></span></th>
        <th class="opp-detail">Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="customer in customerList">
    <tr>
        <td>{{customer.Name}}</td>
        <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.EMail}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsed">
        <td colspan="2">

            <table class="customer-details collapsed table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="opp-detail">Name</th>
                    <th class="opp-detail">Address</th>
                    <th class="opp-detail">City</th>
                    <th class="opp-detail">Zip Code</th>
                    <th class="opp-detail">Contact</th>
                    <th class="opp-detail">Email</th>
                    <th class="opp-detail">Phone</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.Name}}</td>
                    <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.Address}}</td>
                    <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.City}}</td>
                    <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.PostCode}}</td>
                    <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.Contact}}</td>
                    <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.EMail}}</td>
                    <td class="opp-detail">{{customer.PhoneNo}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note 1: If you are using Bootstrap & want to see the table data clearly, just apply  "table" class along with the existing "customer" class and you will see the difference.

Note 2: The problem with your code is the structure of the table. You did not place the child table properly. I made adjustment so that the child table will appear just below the main parent, in a separate row of its own & also moved the "collapsed" class over to the tr tag instead of the nested table. That will help you toggle the row as you see fit. I tested this revised solution with the data & it works fine on my end. Try it out & let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to have nested tables (parent table with customer name, email and child table with more details about customer).

Comment: @intentarr Updated my solution for nested tables.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you, @Devner :)

Comment: @intentarr Glad to help :)